# Computationally faster alternatives to calculate a new variable based on multiple columns from two large data frames in R

Tags: r, performance, bigdata, processing-efficiency

I have two datasets, df1 and df2.

(1) df1 has about 7 million rows and 57 columns. The columns of interest in df1 for this calculation are "county", "start.date", and "end.date".

(2) df2 has about 12 million rows and 12 columns. The columns of interest in df2 for this calculation are "county", "date", and "measure".

For each row i in df1, I need to calculate the mean of all df2$measure[j] that satisfy two conditions:

(a) df2$date[j] is between df1$start.date[i] and df1$end.date[i], and

(b) df2$county[j] matches df1$county[i]

This mean.measure will be added as a new column to df1 for further analysis.

My major problem is computational speed.

My code worked on smaller subsets of data, but when applied full-scale, they took way too long. My parallel computing session (8 CPUs, 8 GB memory) was limited to 8 hours, and even after 8 hours, it was not done yet.

I would truly appreciate your suggestions on how to make this faster, beside using a stronger computer system. Thank you so much in advance!

Below is my code:

```
# Create function to extract mean measure
mean.measure <- function(x,y,z) { # x = county; y = start date; z = end date
  ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(y) | is.na(z), return(NA), 
     ifelse (y >= z, return("Start date >= end date"),
             ifelse (!(x %in% df2$county), return("Nonexistent county"),
                     ifelse(z > max(df2$date) | y < min(df2$date), return("Out of df2 date range"),
                            temp <- df2 %>%
                              filter(county == x & date >= y & date < z) %>% # filter out only the time range and county of interest
                              summarise(mean = mean(measure, na.rm=TRUE)) # ignore NA values for measure
                     )
             )
         )
    )
 return(temp$mean)
}


# Vectorize mean.measure()
v_mean.measure <- Vectorize(mean.measure)

# Calculate mean measure and add to df1
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(mean.measure = v_mean.measure(county,start.date,end.date))
```

Comment: (1) You're misusing `ifelse`, one should never try to `return` from them. I'm not certain if you mean to return out of the function immediately if `any(.)` of them are `NA` (for instance) or if you intend to assign `NA` to that value. (2) "Never" try to assign `<-` something within `ifelse`. There are times when it can work, but it is almost certainly not doing what you need it to do. (3) `%>%` pipes within `ifelse`s are a new level of "don't do this", not sure I've seen that before :-). (4) Your function takes `x`, `y`, and `z`, but you scope-breach to look at `df2`. Not good practice.

Comment: (5) The size of your data certainly makes it challenging; I'm assuming that a non-equi merge/join (using `data.table`, `sqldf`, or the new `dplyr::join_by` will explode memory usage, is that correct? That may be a sign that you need to move your data out-of-memory and just work on one county at a time. There a several methods that might work, ranging from arrow-parquet files to sqlite/duckdb to larger (not monolithic-file-based) database servers. R _can_ work with "big data" (big air quotes there), but it relies wholly on their being another layer to help orchestrate the data. Not R alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by sorting `df2` by `county` then `date`. Then add an index column (`r` in the code below) and a column containing the cumulative sum of `measure` (`cs` below). This will allow us to perform two fast `data.table` non-equi joins to get the start and end rows in `df2` that need to be averaged for each row of `df1`. Use those row indices to get the difference in the cumulative sum of `measure` and then divide by the number of rows making up that difference.

Using some dummy data with 7M rows in `df1` and 12M rows in `df2`, the computation takes only a few seconds.

```
library(data.table)

system.time(
  setDT(df1)[
    , `:=`(
      r1 = setorder(
        setDT(df2),
        county, date
      )[
        , `:=`(r = .I, cs = cumsum(measure))
      ][
        df1,
        r,
        on = .(county == county, date >= start.date),
        mult = "first"
      ],
      r2 = df2[
        df1,
        r,
        on = .(county == county, date < end.date),
        mult = "last"
      ]
    )
  ][
    , `:=`(
      mean.measure = (df2$cs[r2] - df2$cs[r1])/(r2 - r1 + 1L),
      r1 = NULL,
      r2 = NULL
    )
  ]
)
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    5.28    0.31    2.66
```

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  county = sample(LETTERS[1:25], 7e6, 1),
  start.date = sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-31"), "days"), 7e6, 1)
)
df1$end.date <- df1$start.date + sample(1e3, 7e6, 1)
df2 <- data.frame(
  county = sample(LETTERS, 12e6, 1),
  date = sample(seq.Date(as.Date("2010-06-01"), as.Date("2020-07-31"), "days"), 12e6, 1),
  measure = runif(12e6)
)
```

Comment: This by-reference method is sorcery! It works so quickly. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an incremental processing idea.  As r2evans correctly notes, you should not use objects in the R environment directly in a function.  Best practice is to pass them as parameters in your function.  It seems to me that you could preprocess your x counties to ensure that they exist in df2 which would remove the need for the logic checks in your function.  Here is a very simple toy example that breaks a dataframe into feasible subsets and then processes each subset using an `lapply` wrapper:

```
cars <- mtcars
n_cyls <- unique(cars$cyl)

my_function <- function(df_subset) {
      return(mean(df_subset$mpg))
}

means <- lapply(n_cyls, function(x) my_function(subset(cars, cars$cyl == x)))
means
[[1]]
[1] 19.74286

[[2]]
[1] 26.66364

[[3]]
[1] 15.1
```

So in your case you would generate the unique `n_counties` vector from df2 and then pass each df2 subset by county as a parameter to your function.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I was wondering if you could show me how to pass the start and end dates into the function and use lapply, as the mean of the measure is actually over the period defined in each row i of df1 by df1$start.date[i] and df1$end.date[i], not over all the rows with the county of interest. Pardon me for not explaining it well enough - let me know and I can try again!

Comment: For example, if my_function is like this:

mean.measure <- function(start.date,end.date,df2_subset) {
  return(mean(df2_subset$measure[df2_subset$date >= start.date & df2_subset$date < end.date,],na.rm=TRUE))
}

How should I proceed with that for lapply and to extract and start.date and end.date from df1? Thanks again!